# How to make Windows 10 taskbar thumbnail previews bigger?

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, thumbnails, preview

The window previews in Windows 10 are too small to make any informed decisions. How can I increase the size of the thumbnail preview?

[image: Screenshot]

**Note**: This is *not* a duplicate of [Is there any way to make taskbar icons bigger in Windows 10?](https://superuser.com/q/948647/180163) which is about taskbar *icon* size. This question is regarding the preview/thumbnail size.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can do this without any external programs by modifying the registry.  According this video on how to [Make Windows 10 Taskbar Thumbnails Bigger](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3JkWZO41fSQ):

1. Open registry - <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> and type `regedit`
2. Go to path:

   `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband`
3. Add new DWORD 32 Bit Value:

   - **Key**: `MinThumbSizePx`
   - **Value**: Number of pixels anywhere ***less than 500***.
   - **Note**: Choose `Decimal` to set the number of pixels in integers, or convert to hexadecimal

#### Restart Explorer

To see the changes take affect, you must restart explorer with *any* of the following methods:

1. *Longest* - Restart Computer
2. *Medium* - Log off and then log back on
3. *Shortest* <sup>[3](https://www.howtogeek.com/198815/use-this-secret-trick-to-close-and-restart-explorer.exe-in-windows/)</sup>

   1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + Right Click on Taskbar
   2. Select 'Exit Explorer'
   3. Pull up Task Manager (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Esc</kbd>)
   4. File > 'Run New Task' > Type `explorer`
   5. Voila!  You've restarted explorer

[image: Increased Size Screenshot]

---

You can also save the following as a `.reg` file and double click on it:

```ini
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\Taskband]
"MinThumbSizePx"=dword:15e ; 350 (px)
```

Comment: Another fast way to restart explorer is to open up task manager. Find Windows Explorer right click > click restart. This only takes about 15 seconds total.