# How do you make Windows Taskbar list view not truncate long paths?

Tags: windows-explorer, taskbar

I would like to be able to differentiate between several different long paths in windows explorer when I bring up the list view, but I have been unable to find a way to achieve this.

I found HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/CurrentVersion/Explorer/Taskband
which has settings for controlling thumbnail sizes and making list view appear instead of thumbnails, but the size settings do not seem to apply when not in thumbnail mode.

Are there similar keys that would allow me to changed the width of the popup for list view?

The problem is that my explorer list view ends up having multiple paths that are identical, defeating the purpose of displaying the full paths in the title so that I can differentiate which window is which before selecting each one.

C:\LongPath\That\Gets\Truncated\In\List\View\JustBeforeICan\Tell...
C:\LongPath\That\Gets\Truncated\In\List\View\JustBeforeICan\Tell...
C:\LongPath\That\Gets\Truncated\In\List\View\JustBeforeICan\Tell...
C:\LongPath\That\Gets\Truncated\In\List\View\JustBeforeICan\Tell...

When I would like to be able to make it show me something like...
C:\LongPath\That\Gets\Truncated\In\List\View\JustBeforeICan\Tell\Which
C:\LongPath\That\Gets\Truncated\In\List\View\JustBeforeICan\Tell\One
C:\LongPath\That\Gets\Truncated\In\List\View\JustBeforeICan\Tell\I
C:\LongPath\That\Gets\Truncated\In\List\View\JustBeforeICan\Tell\Want

Answer (score -1):

I had the same exact question/frustration. I looked everywhere and it doesn't seem like Windows10 will let you tweak either how the window title is displayed (for example, truncate the beginning of the title instead of the end) or the font size used to display the window title.

What it WILL let you do however, which I ended up doing, is to increase the size of the windows explorer little preview windows. I followed the instructions in this [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/958690/how-to-make-windows-10-taskbar-thumbnail-previews-bigger) by KyleMit which at least allows you to see in most cases the full path of each windows explorer window, at the expense of having to deal with those huge preview windows.